# Javascript addEventListener Anomaly

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

Can someone explain why this does not trigger "listenerFn" twice on click

```
(function () {

    document.querySelector("div").addEventListener("click", listenerFn);
    document.querySelector("div").addEventListener("click", listenerFn);

    function listenerFn() {
        console.log("__testing__");
    } })();
```

while something like below triggers twice as expected :

```
(function () {

myFunction()
myFunction()

function myFunction() {
    function listenerFn() {
        console.log('My Message')
    }
    document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('click', listenerFn)
} })();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that in the first case you are trying to add the same instance of the function listenerFn, and in the second case you are adding two different instances (evenry myFunction() call has its own listnerFn() instance.

You can update your first code example like this and it should work:

```
(function () {

    document.querySelector("div").addEventListener("click", getListenerFn());
    document.querySelector("div").addEventListener("click", getListenerFn());

    function getListenerFn() {
         let listenerFn = function() {
           console.log("__testing__");
        } 

       return listenerFn;
    }
  })();
```

Answer (score 0):

See [the spec](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#add-an-event-listener):

> If eventTarget’s event listener list does not contain an event listener whose type is listener’s type, callback is listener’s callback, and capture is listener’s capture, then append listener to eventTarget’s event listener list.

In the first case you are trying to add the same function as an event listener multiple times.

The first time it adds it.

The second time it doesn't meet the condition "*does not contain … callback is listener’s callback" so it doesn't.

In the second case, you are adding two different (albeit identical) event listeners.

Answer (score 0):

> Because you knew the function twice